# Getting [object Object] error when call JQuery Ajax function for Json data

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm getting the following error when try to read json data from asp.net function, here is the image error 
[image]

Here is the jQuery code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#getdata").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData",                   
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                    // $("#company").html(data.d);
                      console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

what wrong I did to get this error. Appreciate your any help.
getting this error from console log,`console.log(error)`
[image]

Comment: What you return from asp.net method?

Comment: it's result not an error, what your console.log says in success?

Comment: That's because alert() is not a debugging tool, you should be using the console.

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d))` and check whats in the console.

Comment: Try `alert(data.d[0]);`

Comment: I have added the "console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d))" on Success and error section, but not getting anything from Chrome Console

Comment: What do you get in the browser if you go to `Default.aspx/GetData`?

Comment: something like this,{"Table" : [{"Compname" : "Kenworth","compadd1" : "Dana","compadd2" : "Dana","compemail" : "sample@dana.com"}]}. It reading data from a SQL server table and make it as a json string.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing that is that `data.d` is an object representing the returned JSON text response. When you pass in an object into `alert`, it displays `[object Object]`.  Whatever you are looking for will be a property of `data.d`. I would put a breakpoint on that line and see what properties are available. It'll be something like `data.d.myProperty` which will contain the actual string / HTML you are trying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

dont use alert! That will show this only.
Since your response is a Json Object, please try to JSON.stringify it or use console.log to view the data

Comment: I have added the "console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d))" on Success and error section, but not getting anything from Chrome Console

Comment: just do console.log(data)  like this:
 success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
}

Comment: its not showing nothing, do I need to do any settings in Chrome?

Comment: ctrl+shift+I: this will open the developers terminal>
please open the networking tab, then refresh the page, you can then see the server side response coming back. please check the response there

Comment: In response tab i could see the same codes for Default.aspx page

Comment: I just remove the <form> tag, now I'm getting the console log, this is the error,POST http://localhost:50583/Default.aspx/GetData 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:6
send jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) Default.aspx:21
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
v.handle

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what was the issue, I have to add "[WebMethod()]" declaration just before the  asp.net function. For example,

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string GetData()
    {

        try
        {
            string strjson;
            string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            String CmdText = "Select Compname,compadd1,compadd2,compemail from aas_company where compid=@cmpid";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdText, Con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cmpid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 22;
            Con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DA.Fill(DS);
            DataTable dTable = DS.Tables[0];
            strjson = GetJSONString(dTable);
            Con.Close();               
            return strjson;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Error In Get Data" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This answer not for experts only for just beginners, thank you.